# Firebase listener keeps working after logging out

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im currently having a listener attached to one document in one particular screen in my app, it looks like that:

```
const statusHandler = () => {//logging if user is online.
        var ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${PersonalId}/onlineState`)
        ref.on('value', function(snapshot){
            ref.onDisconnect().set(false);
            ref.set(true);
        })
    };
```

If the user closes the app or looses connection to the internet, firebase will set his onlineState to false.

The problem is, after I logout with following function in a different screen:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
    // Sign-out successful.
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
```

The listener doesnt stop. The object within firebase which should be changed to false stays true, only if I close the app and terminate it, it turns to false, therefore I assume the on() listener keeps going even after my logout.
I find this really confusing because even tho I logged out the current user and therefore a connection to the firebase should be canceled in theory, the database doesnt "disconnect" really and keeps running aperently.

This is a problem I dont have with one listener only, but with multiple. Im trying to find an idea on how to unsubscribe from all listeners inside the app at once.

Any idea how I could fix this problem?

Comment: Aside from Shai's answer, also note that a single user (and even a single device) can have multiple connections. Trying to cram all that information is a recipe for problems, which is why the solution in the Firebase documentation uses a separate child node for each connection (notice the `var con = myConnectionsRef.push();` in there). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample

Answer (score 1):

> and therefore a connection to the firebase should be canceled in theory

Why do you assume that?
Note that the connection to this ref is still active, you only signed the user out.

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect) states:

> The OnDisconnect class is used to manage operations that will be run on the server when this **client** disconnects.

This is why when you terminated the app it disconnected and not before.

You can call `Firebase.goOffline()` after the user signs out successfully to force the client to disconnect.

Comment: goOffline() wont work in that case because the listeners keep going inside the app. As soon as I do goOnline() again, the problem occurs again and firebase notices the wrong ongoing listener that should have been terminated.